# html href tag only working on vs code live server extention

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I was prepairing a project which consists of around 13 html files and around 300 files and when i use the live extention of vs code the css is working fine but when i open it directly form file explorer all the href seem to not work including css,to other files and to other html files. I am a student who is still learning stuff so i really dont undersatand what did i do wrong.

[so this is the website opened with live server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmnRI.jpg)

[and this is the website opened from file explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhTfd.png)

[this is my code as well aas the location of css file at the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXxxj.png)

edit: i cannot put the whole code as it is around 2 to 3 thousand lines long in total but i can insert some of it

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> engneering notes at your fingertips </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/10e9a0c57a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="js.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

the above code was stored in F:\webdev\project\html\launcher\main.html

and the css code was stored under  "F:\webdev\project\css\style.css"

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and provide your debugging details in form of a [repro]. Pictures of your code are neither acceptable nor suitable!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You embedded your stylesheet with a path starting with `/css/` - the leading slash makes this a reference relative to the _root_ directory. In case you are calling this via the built-in VS server, that root is the directory the `css`, `html` etc. directories are in. But when you open this via the file system, the root from the browser's perspective is just `F:/` in this case - and your stylesheet is _not_ located under `F:/css/`

Comment: okay so if i want to upload the above project to the server would i have to change the /css/ tag?

Comment: You link your style named *style.css* here ```href="/css/style.css">``` . But name of your css in path is *css.css* It should be the same. Rename your *css.css* to *style.css* then move it's path to **F:\webdev\project\html\lancher\css\style.css**

Comment: @Newbee oh actually i have 2 css file and one named style.css is the main one which had the css code on it and if i do F:\webdev\project\html\lancher\css\style.css then would i be able to run the code on a website as only the project file has the code written in it and the server may look for the webdev tag

Comment: You should **link** them with the correct **path** then.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too once and I figured it out.

When you were defining the **href** for an image, you started the file path with a "**/**" which will cause it to start from the **root folder**. When opening it normally from file explorer, the path to the image will start from your root folder which would be the **hard drive** that it is stored which in your case is "**F:**". So it will look for a folder called **images** which is located on the **F: drive** which doesn't exist.

But when you open it using **live server**, Vs code will see the root directory as the folder that you have opened on vs code. In your case it is "**Project**" and this folder includes the image folder.

When publishing the website on **GitHub pages** for example, if you keep the **image folder directly inside the root folder**, then everything should be fine like how it would show in **live server**.

Comment: @bob No it's not a stupid question I was confused about this before. I think they down-voted because the question is already answered for someone else. I recommend searching the question first before you post it because there might already be someone who asked and someone who answered it.